# Run laravel 5.2 under IP address, view does not work

Tags: view, routes, laravel-5

I have just created a new Laravel 5.2 project with composer and uploaded to my ubuntu 14.04 LTS server, which has Apache 2.4.7. My server does not have domain name, so I must run project based on something like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login. But in this condition, my route file cannot load views.

For example if i have view file with name `login.blade.php`, if in my route file I write:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
});
```

the view file cannot be loaded. But, if in terminal and in the root of my project I type:

```
php public/index.php
```

and then if I refresh the url, the view now loads and works.

What is going on here? I cannot understand what is going on. Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set your laravel permission

```
chown -R apache.apache /var/www/html/yourLaravel
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/yourLaravel
```

if it still not working. you have to set your firewall

```
setenforce 0
```

this command you have to set all the time you restart your server